# Передача методу экземпляр класса

Tags: python, pyqt5

Как передать методу `test` экземпляр `exercise`?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.check_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        # self.check_button.setObjectName("check_button")

        exercise = SecondClass()
        self.check_button.clicked.connect(self.test)

    def test(self):
        print(exercise.attr)


class SecondClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 'value'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    self.exercise = SecondClass()
    self.check_button.clicked.connect(self.test)

def test(self):
    print(self.exercise.attr)
```

Comment: ох уж этот ООП). Благодарю за помощь.